# Runtime and space complexity of recursive and tail-recursive code

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

What is the complexity of the below code to find all subsets of a set of numbers?

```
public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
        subsets.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return find(subsets, nums, 0);
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> find(List<List<Integer>> subsets, int[] nums, int index) {
        if (index == nums.length) {
            return subsets;
        }
        List<List<Integer>> newSubsets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Integer> subset: subsets) {
            List<Integer> newSubset = new ArrayList<>();
            newSubset.addAll(subset);
            newSubset.add(nums[index]);
            newSubsets.add(newSubset);
        }
        subsets.addAll(newSubsets);
        return find(subsets, nums, index + 1);
    }
```

Is it `O(2^nums.length)` as that's the number of subsets there are and you must add each one to the returned list? Also, am I right in thinking that the below version is asymptotically still `O(2^set.size())` but the space complexity contributed by the general recursion is `O(set.size())` whereas in the above tail-recursive code, it is `O(1)`?

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getSubsets(ArrayList<Integer> set) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
    getSubsets(set, subsets, 0);
    return subsets;
}

private static void getSubsets(ArrayList<Integer> set, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets, int index) {
    if (index == set.size()) {
        subsets.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return;
    }
    getSubsets(set, subsets, index + 1);
    int item = set.get(index);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> moreSubsets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ArrayList<Integer> subset: subsets) {
        ArrayList<Integer> newSubset = new ArrayList<>();
        newSubset.addAll(subset);
        newSubset.add(item);
        moreSubsets.add(newSubset);
    }
    subsets.addAll(moreSubsets);
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't do tail call elimination.

Comment: ... but now you are only one step from converting the recursion into an iteration. It will run slightly faster, but you won't save too much memory with the lack of methods call. After a couple of iterations the subsets will allocate much-much more memory than the stackframe.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the main problem here is data-space complexity. Your code will throw OutOfMemoryError if the length of the original array is more than a few dozen. A few more element and all of the memory-chips and hard-drives on Earth won't be enough to store the subsets.

Saving a few bytes by optimizing it to tail-recursive doesn't make a difference.

For practical purpose the following code is much efficient. Although it's slower in general, but it's data-space complexity is O(N) and it calculates the subsets on the fly so it can even give you a better result if you want to process only certain subsets.

```
private static List<Integer> getSubset(int[] nums, BigInteger n) {
    List<Integer> subset = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (n.testBit(i)) {
            subset.add(nums[i]);
        }
    }
    return subset;
}
```

You can access the subsets like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    for (BigInteger n = new BigInteger("2").pow(nums.length).subtract(BigInteger.ONE); n
            .compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) >= 0; n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        // process nth subset
        // each subset is identified by n where 0<=n<2^nums.lenght
        System.out.println(getSubset(nums, n));
    }
}
```